# Equivalent metrics on Fréchet spaces and Lipschitz maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Lipschitz maps are defined over metric space as maps $f:(X,d_X) \to (Y,d_Y)$ such that
$$ d\left( f(x),f(x^\prime) \right)_Y \le k d(x,x^\prime)_X \ \forall x,x^\prime \in X, $$
where $k$ is a positive constant. We usually say that $f$ is a *contraction* if $k<1$.

It is well know that a different equivalent metric on $X$ does not preserve contractions, i.e. a map can be a contraction with respect to a metric but not with respect to an equivalent one.

In the Banach space setting, where the spaces $X$ and $Y$ are endowed with a norm defining the topology, there is a somehow "canonical" distance given by
$$ d(x,x^\prime) = \lVert x-x^\prime \rVert .$$
With this distance, Lipschitz maps can be characterized as maps satisfying, for some $k>0$
$$ {\left\lVert f(x) - f(x^\prime) \right\rVert}_Y \le k {\left \lVert x-x^\prime \right \rVert}_X \ \forall x, x^\prime \in X. $$
It is obvious that, if $f$ satisfies the above relation, then is a $k$-lipschitz map.

---

In the Fréchet space setting, the topology is defined by a countable family of semi-norms $({\lVert\cdot\rVert}_n)$. The classical example of metric inducing the same topology is given by
$$ d(x,x^\prime) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2^{-n}} \frac{{\lVert x-x^\prime\rVert}_n}{1+{\lVert x-x^\prime\rVert}_n} . $$

In analogy with the Banach case, I would like to characterize (at least some) Lipschtiz maps between Fréchet spaces as maps satisfying
$$ {\left\lVert f(x) - f(x^\prime) \right\rVert}_n \le k {\left \lVert x-x^\prime \right \rVert}_n \ \forall x, x^\prime \in X,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. $$
Again, maps satisfying the last equation **are** Lipschitz maps with respect to the metric defined above, but the Lipschitz constant is not $k$ anymore, and in particular contraction with respect to the semi-norms (i.e. maps satisfying the last equation with $k<1$) are not contraction with respect to the metric.

Are there equivalent distances on $X$ and $Y$ such that *every* contraction with respect to the semi-norms is a contraction with respect with the new distance? If this is not possibile for *every* contraction, is it possible for a specific one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $\sum 2^{-n}(\|x-y\|_n  \wedge 1)$ for the distance on $Y$ and $\sum 2^{-n}(\|x-y\|_n  \wedge 2)$ for the distance on $X$.

Comment: I understand the idea, but I would say that if I take `$ \sum 2^{-n} ({\left\lVert x-y\right\rVert} \wedge 1)$` on `$X$`, I need `$\sum 2^{-n} ({\left\lVert x-y\right\rVert} \wedge 1/k)$` on `$Y$`.

Anyway... what about maps from `$X$` into himself? Are maps `$f:X\toX$` satisfying `$\left\lVert f(x) -f(y)\right\rVert \le k \left \lVert x-y \right \rVert$`, with `$k<1$`, distance-contraction (and thus have a unique fixed point)?

maybe this is a different question...

Comment: I meant `$\sum 2^{-n} (\left\lVert x-y \right\rVert \wedge k)$` on `$Y$`.

Comment: As for having the same distance on `$X$` and `$Y$` when `$X=Y$`, that is not possible when e.g. `$X$` is the countable product of lines.  For this space $I/2$ is not a contraction under any compatible metric. 



Comment: ...but it still has a unique fixed point, right?

Comment: Sure; zero.  I is the identity operator.